# What is a domain server?

Tags: dns, domaincontroller

I've been looking around and I'm struggling to discover if a domain server is different than a domain name server, which I understand to be a server that maps URL names to IP addresses.

Are these two things different? Is it a different shorthand for DNS?

Comment: A domain controller is the server running Active Directory; Domain controllers are typically referred as DC. Domain controller is a server based on MS windows Server 200X which is responsible for allowing host access to domain resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Domain server AKA [domain controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_controller) is a server computer that responds to security authentication requests (logging in, checking permissions, etc.) within a Windows domain.

A domain name server (DNS) maps domains names to IP addresses, in a nutshell, as you said.

**They are not related, not a shorthand**.